Какое местоимение правильно употребить?
Какое местоимение правильно употребить? Зовёшь пойти с СОБОЙ или с ТОБОЙ. Не могу найти правило, которое регламентирует употребление в данном случае. Спасибо!

Правильно:
Зовёшь (меня) пойти с тобой.
Пояснение:

Розенталь  §170. Возвратные и притяжательные местоимения
Возвратное местоимение себя может относиться к любому из 
трех грамматических лиц, поэтому при наличии в 
предложении нескольких существительных или местоимений, с 
которыми потенциально может соотноситься возвратное 
местоимение, нередко возникает неясность. Например: 
Комендант велел дворнику отнести вещи жильца к себе (к 
коменданту или к дворнику?). В подобных случаях 
возвратное местоимение следует относить к слову, 
называющему производителя соответствующего действия: 
действие коменданта выразилось в том, что он велел, а 
действие, выраженное инфинитивом отнести, относится к 
дворнику; поскольку сочетание к себе синтаксически 
зависит от последнего глагола (отнести к себе), то тем 
самым возвратное местоимение соотносится с 
существительным дворник.


Возвратные местоимения свой, себя, собой используются при обозначении действия,  обращенного к производителю действия.


Зовёшь (меня) пойти с тобой.
Надо смотреть, кто совершает действие. Пойти должен я, но сам с собой я не могу пойти (некорректный вариант). Я должен пойти с тобой.

Сравнить: Приглашаешь меня с собой.

Здесь совершаешь действие ты, поэтому с собой. Это естественный вариант при обозначении возвратного действия.
Но: Пригласили нас с тобой.
